# Taxonomy term view - show node fields in the view?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Ive enabled the default view 'Taxonomy term' which overrides taxonomy term pages. How can I add fields for my nodes? Currently it says 'The selected style or row format does not utilize fields.' Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right above "Fields" that you can't change is "Format".  It's set to "Show: Content" by default.  Change that to "Show: Fields".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of Views "Format" you are using. For example if you have JSON data document/ Table / etc., you can change its "Field output" to Normal (if you have "Raw" it will echo only correspond id)